# Lowest count for each object

Tags: php, mysql

In my code i print count of student for each subject in different days  .. iwant to get the lowest  student count day  for each subject

```
$distinctdate=$connection->query("SELECT distinct exam_dates FROM Examdata  ORDER BY `Examdata`.`exam_dates` ASC")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$b=$connection->query("SELECT distinct Subject_ID FROM SSSD ")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$c="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CO 
(coo varchar(255));";
$cc=mysqli_query($connection,$c);

foreach($b as $s1){
    echo '<br>'.$s1['Subject_ID'].'<br>';
    $qq=$s1['Subject_ID'];


    $gg="INSERT INTO CO SELECT DISTINCT Student_ID From Examdata where `Subject_ID`='$qq'";
    $kk=mysqli_query($connection,$gg);
    foreach( $distinctdate as $dis){
       echo $dis['exam_dates'].'<br>';
        $qdis=$dis['exam_dates'];
    $date= "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT`Student_ID`)Q FROM Examdata WHERE `Student_ID` in (SELECT `coo` FROM CO )
    and `exam_dates`='$qdis' and `Subject_ID`!='$qq'";
    $dddddd=mysqli_query($connection,$date);
    while($nnnnn=mysqli_fetch_array($dddddd)){
        $j=$nnnnn['Q'];
        echo "Count".$j.'<br>';
    }

}
    $DELETE="DELETE FROM CO";
    $DELETEE=mysqli_query($connection,$DELETE);
}
```

[Now it’s look like this but i want the lowest count for each](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQV8J.png)

Comment: Pls format your source code so it is easier to read. Also describe each part of your code

Comment: I started looking at this, but after seeing variable names $c, $cc, $qq, $gg, $kk, $dddddd and $nnnnn I got lost. It would be best if you described the tables you are starting with, some sample data, and what the end result would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sql function COUNT() along with the function MIN().

There is an exemple here -> https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/min-count.php

I hope it helps.